# Keep iTunes movies and TV shows on iPad for offline viewing?

Tags: ipad, airplane-mode

When I purchase a TV show or movie on my iPad from the iTunes Store it goes directly to the cloud. I want it to stay on my iPad so I can watch it on the plane in offline mode. I checked and I do have 2 GB of space available.

How do I download the content to my iPad?

Comment: 2GB is probably not sufficient for more than 1 movie or a couple of TV episodes (and that might even be a stretch). You will need to clear more space first.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to enable viewing your cloud content on your iPad. This is done from the Settings app. Go to: `Settings.app > iTunes & App Store` and under the `Show All` section make sure `Videos` is set to green.

Now go to the `Videos` app on your iPad and you'll be able to see all your cloud-based video content you've purchased.

To download a movie or show for offline viewing, tap the icon for the show and on the show detail screen, in the upper right hand corner, is a little cloud icon with an arrow pointing down in it. Like this:

[image]

Press that button and, assuming you have enough free space on your iPad, the video will download and be available to you to view when the iPad is in airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017 (I literally did this this morning, 18-Apr-2017):

1. In itunes on your laptop, you can download the movie.
2. When you sync your ipad, you can select that movie to be synced to the ipad. You do that by looking at the ipad as it's syncing, selecting "Movies" from the folder list on the left sidebar, and selecting each movie you want to sync.
3. After sync, on your ipad, you will have to go to the "TV" app. The "Videos" app is no longer.
4. Select Library. In the upper left there is a dropdown menu (not glaringly obvious). Select "downloaded." The selection of downloaded movies will be displayed.

And yes, 2GB is probably not enough for a typical Hollywood movie. For comparison: Elf is 3.95gb according to itunes.